# Oracle Select from multiple Tables?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I have multiple Tables in Oracle which have primary keys and foreign keys linking to each other. The tables are:

```
Continent
Sub-Continent
Country
Region
City
Location
```

As example of how the layout is for each:

```
continent_id      | continent_name
1                 | Africa
2                 | America

sub_continent_id  | sub_continent_name  | continent_id
A1                | Southern Africa     | 1
B1                | Western Africa      | 1
A2                | North America       | 2
B2                | South America       | 2

country_id        | country_name        | sub_continent_id
CAN               | Canada              | A2
ZA                | South Africa        | A1
```

This continues for the rest: `Region`, `City` and `Location`.
As can be seen, the ID's reference another table. So:

`country_name` "Canada" references `sub_continent_id` "A2" which is "North
America". "North America" references `continent_id` 2 which is "Americas".

What I want to try and do is to run a SQL query that if I chose a location, it should return the rest of the values from other tables. So if I select a location called "Triange Building", it will automatically return:

```
Triangle Building, New York City, New York, North America, Americas
```

I am uncertain of what query to run to collect all these values each time.

I can run a single query like this to show me region name and city name, but do not know how to select more values from more Tables.

```
SELECT E.city_name NAME,D.region_name DNAME
FROM CITY E JOIN REGION D
ON (E.region_id = D.region_id);
```

Comment: Just start with another JOIN after the ON clause, you should have E and D available for that other join ON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just join all the tables

```
SELECT E.city_name as NAME, D.region_name as DNAME, C.COUNTRY_NAME, SC.SUB_CONTINENT_NAME, 
       CO.CONTINENT_NAME
FROM  CITY E JOIN REGION        D  ON  E.region_id        =  D.region_id
             JOIN COUNTRY       C  ON  D.country_id       =  C.country_id
             JOIN SUB-CONTINENT SC ON  C.sub_continent_id = SC.sub_continent_id
             JOIN CONTINENT     CO ON SC.continent_id     = CO.continent_id;
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I feel really stupid now, did not know it was that simple.

Comment: @user2082599 - don't feel stupid. Perfectly legitimate question, and the way you described the problem, how the tables are related to each other, using primary and foreign keys exactly the right way etc. indicates the opposite of stupid.

Comment: @user2082599 Mathguy is right, the question was perfectly asked. Way above average.